# Django Oscar Image saved in cache folder but not showing

Tags: python, django, django-oscar

Could anyone point me the direction to solve the image not displaying properly, since the image was saved in cache folder with 500 error. I am not sure if it is to due to permission or something deeper?

This is what I had configure but not sure if I doing it right.

URLS.py:

```
from django.apps import apps
from django.urls import include, path
from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from oscar.views import handler403, handler404, handler500

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include(apps.get_app_config('oscar').urls[0])),
]

if settings.DEBUG:
    import debug_toolbar

    # Server statics and uploaded media
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
    # Allow error pages to be tested
    urlpatterns += [
        path('403', handler403, {'exception': Exception()}),
        path('404', handler404, {'exception': Exception()}),
        path('500', handler500),
        path('__debug__/', include(debug_toolbar.urls)),
    ]
```

Setting.py:

```
# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static/')

MEDIA_ROOT = '/media/'
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

THUMBNAIL_DEBUG = DEBUG
THUMBNAIL_KEY_PREFIX = 'oscar-sandbox'
THUMBNAIL_KVSTORE = env(
    'THUMBNAIL_KVSTORE',
    default='sorl.thumbnail.kvstores.cached_db_kvstore.KVStore')
THUMBNAIL_REDIS_URL = env('THUMBNAIL_REDIS_URL', default=None)


STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.storage.CompressedManifestStaticFilesStorage'
 
STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
)
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. I was helped by adding in urls.py applications
url string

```
templates += static (settings. MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings. MEDIA_ROOT)
```

In settings.py were also added:

```
# Path helper
location = lambda x: os.path.join(
    os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)), x)

# Absolute path to the directory that holds media.
# Example: "/home/media/media.lawrence.com/"
MEDIA_ROOT = location("public/media")

# URL that handles the media served from MEDIA_ROOT. Make sure to use a
# trailing slash if there is a path component (optional in other cases).
# Examples: "http://media.lawrence.com", "http://example.com/media/"
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = location('public/static')
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.storage.CompressedManifestStaticFilesStorage'
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    location('static/'),
)
```